# Null Pointer Exception error while passing value from one methord to another

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, collections, nullpointerexception

I am trying to return the last index value of the ArrayDeque q from methord distributeTicket() of class Solution to the methord main() of class GFG.

```
//{ Driver Code Starts
//Initial Template for Java

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class GFG{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        while (t-- > 0) {
            String s[]=in.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            int n=Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
            int k=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
            Solution ob=new Solution();
            out.println(ob.distributeTicket(n,k));
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
// } Driver Code Ends

//User function Template for Java
class Solution {
    public static int distributeTicket(int N,int K)
    {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
            q.add(i);
        }
        
        while(true){
            if(K==1 && q.size()==2)
                return q.peekLast();//.intValue();
            
            if(q.size() > K){
                for(int i=1;i<=K;i++)
                    q.pollFirst();
                
                for(int i=1;i<=K;i++)
                    q.pollLast();
            }
            
            else
                return q.peekLast();//.intValue();
        }
    }
}
```

While executing the code with custom input, the code is giving the expected out.

```
For Input: 
25 1
Your Output: 
13
Expected Output: 
13
```

But while submitting the code, its throwing an exception.

```
For Input: 
25 1
Your Output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Solution.distributeTicket(File.java:48)
    at GFG.main(File.java:17)

Its Correct output is:
13
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and what is the solution.

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between "_custom input_" and "_submitting the code_"? `return q.peekLast()` looks being the cause of your `NullPointerException` because `q` hasn't be filled by the `for` loop. It's my guess. I recommend you to put a breakpoint on the line: `q.add(i)` to verify that you are really executing it, at least once.

Comment: Question is __impossible__ to answer: The pasted distributeTicket method __cannot possibly__ throw NPEs itself. The explanation is something that goes beyond what the ticket describes, such as 'the auto-grader tool is _not_ running this code, but some older code you wrote' or 'the auto-grader tool is straight up broken'. Voted to close.

Comment: @MarcLeBehan The pasted code cannot result in `q` being `null` at any point in its execution, hence, your guess is definitely incorrect. Given that OP is clearly complaining about an auto-grader's output, they __cant__ breakpoint it. Unless the auto-grader supports that. No auto-grader does - It doesn't make sense to assume it would.

Comment: When I ran the code with _25_ and _1_, there was no _NullPointerException_.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this line in between the 2 fors `if (q.size() <= K) return q.getFirst();` the error message you were getting is not for the `25 1` but you can get the null pointer if you input `24 2`

```
  public static int distributeTicket(int N, int K) {
            ArrayDeque<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                q.add(i);
            }
            while (true) {
                if (K == 1 && q.size() == 2) return q.getLast();
                if (q.size() > K) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= K; i++) {
                        q.pollFirst();
                    }
                    if (q.size() <= K) return q.getFirst();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= K; i++) {
                        q.pollLast();
                    }
                } else {
                    return q.getLast();
                }
            }
        }
```